# UDP Flood to Host in the firewall logs

Tags: networking, router, firewall, udp

When the router's firewall logs shows as follows

`UDP Flood to Host PRIVATE_LAN_CLIENT_IP, PORT ->> EXTERNAL_PUBLIC_IP, PORT (from WAN Outbound)`.

Will those packets be routed to the private lan client (or) will routers firewall discards them?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the router's firewall: it may have just a LOG rule and therefore just tell you that a flood is happening or it may have a LOG and DROP rule and then discard the packets.

It may happen that the "flood" actually is a normal usage (for example some fast speed streaming) or being really a flood.

In either case: it really depends on the specific firewall configuration, I'm sorry there is not a definitive answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the default configuration for routers is not forward anything unless you specifically added forward rules to your router  firewall, or put your IP in the DMZ.